# Handsontable Gem: adding different placeholder text to different cells in a row

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, handsontable

I'd like to make the first row read only - which I've done - and include placeholder values for the data input requirements, e.g., a date format of yyyy-mm-dd.  I can add placeholder values to all cells (by setting the Placeholder property), but can't figure out how to add a placeholder to a single cell.  Thanks in advance for your help.

```
var placeHolders = {
  "course_id": "ABC ",
  "class_date": "YYYY-MM-DD",
  "sponsor_name": "ICPAS",
  "title": "How to",
  "subject": "Audit",
  "description": "Auditing 101",
  "hours_preparation": "2.0",
  "hours_presentation": "2.0",
  "hours_semester": "2.0",
  "hours_quarter": "2.0",
  "hours_earned": "2.0",
  "price": "25.00",
  "link": "www.bastute.com"
};

var data = [];

var greenRenderer = function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
  Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
  td.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  };

var data = [];

function strip_tags(input, allowed) {
  // +   original by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  allowed = (((allowed || "") + "").toLowerCase().match(/<[a-z][a-z0-9]*>/g) || []).join(''); // making sure the allowed arg is a string containing only tags in lowercase (<a><b><c>)
  var tags = /<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>/gi,
    commentsAndPhpTags = /<!--[\s\S]*?-->|<\?(?:php)?[\s\S]*?\?>/gi;
  return input.replace(commentsAndPhpTags, '').replace(tags, function ($0, $1) {
    return allowed.indexOf('<' + $1.toLowerCase() + '>') > -1 ? $0 : '';
  });
};


var safeHtmlRenderer = function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
  var escaped = Handsontable.helper.stringify(value);
  escaped = strip_tags(escaped, '<em><b><strong><a><big>'); //be sure you only allow certain HTML tags to avoid XSS threats (you should also remove unwanted HTML attributes)
  td.innerHTML = escaped;
  return td;
};

function negativeValueRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
  Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
  if (parseInt(value, 10) < 0) { //if row contains negative number
    td.className = 'negative'; //add class "negative"
  }
  if (!value || value === '') {
    td.style.background = '#EEE';
  }
};

Handsontable.renderers.registerRenderer('negativeValueRenderer', negativeValueRenderer); //maps function to lookup string

var container = document.getElementById('hot');
var hot = new Handsontable(container,
  {
    data: [],
    dataSchema: {course_id: null, class_date: null, sponsor_name: null, title: null, subject: null, description: null, hours_preparation: null, hours_presentation: null, hours_semester: null, hours_quarter: null, hours_earned: null, price: null, link: null},
    columns: [{
        data: "course_id",
        placeholder: placeHolders.course_id
      },{
        data: "class_date",
        placeholder: placeHolders.class_date
      },{
        data: "sponsor_name",
        placeholder: placeHolders.sponsor_name
      },{
        data: "title",
        placeholder: placeHolders.title
      },{
        data: "subject",
        placeholder: placeHolders.subject
      },{
        data: "description",
        placeholder: placeHolders.description
      },{
        data: "hours_preparation",
        placeholder: placeHolders.hours_preparation
      },{
        data: "hours_presentation",
        placeholder: placeHolders.hours_presentation
      },{
        data: "hours_semester",
        placeholder: placeHolders.hours_semester
      },{
        data: "hours_quarter",
        placeholder: placeHolders.hours_quarter
      },{
        data: "hours_earned",
        placeholder: placeHolders.hours_earned
      },{
        data: "price",
        placeholder: placeHolders.price
      },{
        data: "link",
        placeholder: placeHolders.link
      } ],
    startRows: 25,
    startCols: 13,
    currentRowClassName: 'currentRow',
    currentColClassName: 'currentCol',
    autoColumnSize: true,
    autoRowSize: true, 
    autoWrapCol: true,
    autoWrapRow: true,
    rowHeaders: true,
    colWidths: [50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50],
    colHeaders: ["Course<br/>Id", "Class<br/>Date", "Sponsor<br/>Name", "<br/>Title", "<br/>Subject", "<br/>Description", "Hours<br/>Preparation", "Hours<br/>Presentation", "Hours<br/>Semester", "Hours<br/>Quarter", "Hours<br/>Earned", "<br/>Price", "<br/>Link"],
    stretchH: 'all',
    maxRows: 25,
    minRows: 25,
    minSpareRows: 1,
    contextMenu: true,
    contextMenuCopyPaste: {
        swfPath: "assets/ZeroClipboard.swf"
      },
    onSelection: function (row, col, row2, col2) {
      var meta = this.getCellMeta(row2, col2);
      if (meta.readOnly) {
        this.updateSettings({fillHandle: false});
      }
      else {
        this.updateSettings({fillHandle: true});
      }
    },
    cells: function (row, col, prop) {
      var cellProperties = {};
      if (row === 26 || this.instance.getData()[row][col] === 'readOnly') {

        cellProperties.readOnly = true; //make cell read-only if it is first row or the text reads 'readOnly'
      }
      else {
        cellProperties.renderer = "negativeValueRenderer"; //uses lookup map
      }
      return cellProperties;
    },
    columns: [
      {data: "course_id", type: 'text', renderer: safeHtmlRenderer},
       //'text' is default, you don't actually have to declare it  
      {data: "class_date", type: 'date', renderer: safeHtmlRenderer},
      {data: "sponsor_name", type: 'text', renderer: safeHtmlRenderer},
      {data: "title", type: 'text', renderer: safeHtmlRenderer},
      {data: "subject", type: 'text', renderer: safeHtmlRenderer},
      {data: "description", type: 'text', renderer: safeHtmlRenderer},
      {data: "hours_preparation", type: 'numeric', renderer: safeHtmlRenderer},
      {data: "hours_presentation", type: 'numeric', renderer: safeHtmlRenderer},
      {data: "hours_semester", type: 'numeric', renderer: safeHtmlRenderer},
      {data: "hours_quarter", type: 'numeric', renderer: safeHtmlRenderer},
      {data: "hours_earned", type: 'numeric', renderer: safeHtmlRenderer},
      {data: "price", type: 'numeric', renderer: safeHtmlRenderer},
      {data: "link", type: 'text', renderer: safeHtmlRenderer}
      ]
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by adding to a single cell? The placeholder property is generally added to each column. Can you gives us a better example? Placeholders are generally used for new lines since as soon as data is in them, you stop having a need for them. So what do you mean by single cell?

Comment: Let's say I have a table with five columns.  If I set the placeholder property to true, `placeholder: true` or `placeholder: a_string`, the value appears in all cells in the table.  What I want to do in the first row is show examples of the column header's format, e.g., column 'date' and placeholder YYYY-MM-DD or phone, 'xxx-xxx-xxxx' in the cell immediately below the header (which I've set as read only).  Thanks

Comment: I posted my code.  I'm not sure what I'm missing.  I you can take a look at it again, I'd appreciate it.  Incidentally, I didn't add data because this is for uploads only.  Thanks.

Comment: could you please post it to a jsFiddle? it's a lot of code to just be looking at and it'd make all our lives easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is the standard way of setting placeholders which is the following:

If you look in HOT documentation, you will see that for advanced tasks like yours, setting the `columns` option is important. This is an array of objects where each object is a column with its properties. In your case, you'd want to set the property `placeholder` to the string that you'd like, or to a function that will calculate it based on whatever you decide is needed.

Below is an example where I've set different placeholders for each column.

[jSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/zekedroid/wtzm7Lt1/1/)

Comment: Now working; I made a mistake following your example before.  Thank you.  I'm accepting your answer.